# Toggle arrow rotation is not working using expandable text inside fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

I am doing a code inside a fragment class. I want to put a cardview with textview that when I clicked the arrow, the layout will expand. But, I am getting an error now on the toggle arrow section.

Hoping that anyone could help me. Thank you!

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">   

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:scrollingCache="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="56dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    app:cardElevation="2dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@android:color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                            <View
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_large"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/about_intro_header"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                                android:textColor="@color/grey_80" />
                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/introduction_toggle_text"
                                android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                                android:tint="@color/grey_80"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_head_down" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/introduction_expand_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_large"
                                android:text="@string/about_introduction" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Layout.java**

```
package com.sample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import com.sample.utils.Tools;
import com.sample.utils.ViewAnimation;

public class Layout extends Fragment {

    private View parent_view;
    private ImageButton introduction_toggle_text;
    private NestedScrollView nested_scroll_view;
    private View introduction_expand_text;

    public Layout() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
        rootview.findViewById(R.id.nested_scroll_view);

        rootview.findViewById(R.id.introduction_expand_text).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rootview.findViewById(R.id.introduction_toggle_text).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggleSectionText(introduction_toggle_text);
            }
        });


        return rootview;
    }

    private void toggleSectionText(View view) {
        boolean show = toggleArrow(view);
        if (show) {
            ViewAnimation.expand(introduction_expand_text, new ViewAnimation.AnimListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Tools.nestedScrollTo(nested_scroll_view, introduction_expand_text);
                }
            });
        } else {
            ViewAnimation.collapse(introduction_expand_text);
        }
    }

    public boolean toggleArrow(View view) {
        if (view.getRotation() == 0) {
            view.animate().setDuration(200).rotation(180);
            return true;
        } else {
            view.animate().setDuration(200).rotation(0);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**This is the error displaying in my logcat.**

```
2021-03-15 14:56:42.770 8995-8995/com.sample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nuevaecijatourism.neverending, PID: 8995
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float android.view.View.getRotation()' on a null object reference
        at com.sample.Layout.toggleArrow(About.java:59)
        at com.sample.Layout.toggleSectionText(About.java:45)
        at com.sample.Layout.access$100(About.java:14)
        at com.sample.Layout$1.onClick(About.java:35)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7265)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7221)
        at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:836)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27927)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7802)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
2021-03-15 14:56:42.781 8995-8995/com.sample I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8995 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the `public View onCreateView` , before use the `introduction_toggle_text`:

Try change code as below:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
        rootview.findViewById(R.id.nested_scroll_view);

        rootview.findViewById(R.id.introduction_expand_text).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        introduction_toggle_text = rootview.findViewById(R.id.introduction_toggle_text);
        introduction_toggle_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggleSectionText(introduction_toggle_text);
            }
        });

        return rootview;
    }
```